# web bluetooth - `getPrimaryService` call gets stuck

Tags: progressive-web-apps, web-bluetooth, sunmi

I'm trying to print from a device from a PWA - the device is https://www.sunmi.com/en/v2-pro/ - I can connect to the device, but when I try to get the service, the promise gets stuck i.e. neither the "catch" nor the "finally" callbacks are called.

```js
navigator.bluetooth.requestDevice({
  acceptAllDevices: true,
  optionalServices: ['00001101-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb'],
})
  .then((device) => {
    console.log('> Found ' + device.name);
    console.log('Connecting to GATT Server...');
    return device.gatt.connect();
  })
  .then((server) => {
    console.log('> Connected ' + server.connected);
    console.log('getPrimaryService...');
    return server.getPrimaryService('00001101-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb');
  })
  .then((service) => {
    console.log('getCharacteristic...');
    return service.getCharacteristic('00001101-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb');
  })
  .then((characteristic) => {
    console.log('> Characteristic UUID: ' + characteristic.uuid);
  })
  .catch((error) => {
    console.log('Argh! ' + error);
  })
  .finally(() => {
    console.log('> Finally');
  });

console.log('whatsup?');
```

https://share.getcloudapp.com/5zuLxBE4 - the logs until "getPrimaryService...". The device does not show any dialog or requests any interaction. So not sure why this would get stuck.

I've used the nRF connect app to get the uuid - https://share.getcloudapp.com/GGulYQYz

Not sure if I'm doing something wrong here, any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

This is probably an implementation issue, as the browser needs to call out to the operating system to get the list of primary services and this can fail for a myriad of reasons. Can you file an bug report on the issue tracker for the browser you are using (e.g. crbug.com for Google Chrome) with details about the device and operating system on which you are encountering this issue? It would also be useful information to know if this issue occured on multiple platforms (e.g. Android and Windows).

Answer (score 0):

The `"00001101-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb"` UUID you use is the one used for the standardised Serial Port Profile (SPP).

According to https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/azure/en-US/e3466b1f-b67a-4217-ab53-c64921493ec1/what-bluetooth-service-is-needed-to-connect-a-remote-device-to-a-windows-10-virtual-port?forum=wdk, SPP is **not** supported on BLE devices.

I'm surprised though the `getPrimaryService()` promise does not reject. As suggested by Reilly Grant, please file a bug. See https://sites.google.com/a/chromium.org/dev/developers/how-tos/file-web-bluetooth-bugs